# How do I get C# multidimensional List into SSIS object variable?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, ssis

I receive a CSV file from an external vendor multiple times per week which contains a varying number of blank cells, text qualifiers, and often is missing row delimiters, causing my existing Flat File Connection to fail the SSIS package. It takes a day+ to receive a corrected file, which then causes significant problems from a business standpoint.

I have been developing a C# Script Task to import the CSV file into a multidimensional List, and have been able to successfully output the List contents to a Message Box. However, when I attempt to pass the values from the List to my Object Variable I receive an error stating "The element cannot be found in a collection".

What do I need to do differently in order to pass the List data into the Object Variable? Here is my existing code, with comments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {       

        public void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                //string dataRow;

                FileStream fileName = new FileStream(Dts.Variables["ImportFilename"].Value.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                var column1 = new List<string>();
                var column2 = new List<string>();
                var column3 = new List<string>();
                var column4 = new List<string>();
                var column5 = new List<string>();
                var column6 = new List<string>();
                var column7 = new List<string>();
                var column8 = new List<string>();
                var column9 = new List<string>();
                var column10 = new List<string>();

                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(',');
                        column1.Add(splits[0]);
                        column2.Add(splits[1]);
                        column3.Add(splits[2]);
                        column4.Add(splits[3]);
                        column5.Add(splits[4]);
                        column6.Add(splits[5]);
                        column7.Add(splits[6]);
                        column8.Add(splits[7]);
                        column9.Add(splits[8]);
                        column10.Add(splits[9]);
                    }

                }
                var mergedColumns = new List<String>(column1.Count +
                                                     column2.Count +
                                                     column3.Count +
                                                     column4.Count +
                                                     column5.Count +
                                                     column6.Count +
                                                     column7.Count +
                                                     column8.Count +
                                                     column9.Count +
                                                     column10.Count);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column1);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column2);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column3);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column4);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column5);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column6);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column7);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column8);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column9);
                mergedColumns.AddRange(column10);

                //THIS IS RETURNING ALL THE VALUES FROM ALL COLUMNS
                string msg = string.Empty;

                foreach (string x in mergedColumns)
                {
                    msg += x.ToString() + "\r\n";
                }

                MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());

                //RETURNS "The element cannot be found in a collection" ERROR.
                Dts.Variables["importFile"].Value = mergedColumns;

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "ErrorMessage", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
```

UPDATE 2016-07-07:

Based on the suggestions I've made these updates to my code. I think I'm close, but I've not been able to figure out two problems:

1.) Each of my td.Columns.Add lines generate the error "Identifier expected", but I don't know what I need to do to correct it?

2.) The inner foreach loop states "...does not contain a definition for 'Keys' and no extension method 'Keys' accepting a first argument type of...could be found..." I don't think I'm missing a reference, but I'm not sure what is wrong?

Here's my current code, any suggestions?

```
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    //THIS WORKS
    public class Schip
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ResidentState { get; set; }
        public string ResidentStateAbbreviation { get; set; }
        public string NonResidentState { get; set; }
        public string NonResidentStateAbbreviation { get; set; }
        public string IssueDate { get; set; }
        public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public string InternalUserID { get; set; }
    }



    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            //THIS WORKS
            FileStream fileName = new FileStream(Dts.Variables["ImportFilename"].Value.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            List<Schip> adjImport = new List<Schip>();

            StreamReader rd1 = new StreamReader(fileName);

            while (!rd1.EndOfStream)
            {
                var split = rd1.ReadLine().Split(',');
                adjImport.Add(new Schip
                {
                    UserId = split[0],
                    FirstName = split[1],
                    LastName = split[2],
                    ResidentState = split[3],
                    ResidentStateAbbreviation = split[4],
                    NonResidentState = split[5],
                    NonResidentStateAbbreviation = split[6],
                    IssueDate = split[7],
                    ExpirationDate = split[8],
                    InternalUserID = split[9]
                });
            }

            rd1.Dispose();

            //THIS WORKS
            DataTable td = new DataTable("td");
            td.Clear();
            td.Columns.Add("UserId");
            td.Columns.Add("FirstName");
            td.Columns.Add("LastName");
            td.Columns.Add("ResidentState");
            td.Columns.Add("ResidentStateAbbreviation");
            td.Columns.Add("NonResidentState");
            td.Columns.Add("NonResidentStateAbbreviation");
            td.Columns.Add("IssueDate");
            td.Columns.Add("ExpirationDate");
            td.Columns.Add("InternalUserID");


            //THIS GENERATES "Identifier expected" ERRORS ON EACH ROW
            //AND NO DEFINITION FOR "Keys".
            foreach (Schip schip in adjImport)
            {
                DataRow newRow = td.NewRow();
                foreach(string column in schip.Keys)
                {
                    newRow["AdjusterId"] = schip.["AdjusterId"];
                    newRow["FirstName"] = schip.["FirstName"];
                    newRow["LastName"] = schip.["LastName"];
                    newRow["ResidentState"] = schip.["ResidentState"];
                    newRow["ResidentStateAbbreviation"] = schip.["ResidentStateAbbreviation"];
                    newRow["NonResidentState"] = schip.["NonResidentState"];
                    newRow["NonResidentStateAbbreviation"] = schip.["NonResidentStateAbbreviation"];
                    newRow["IssueDate"] = schip.["IssueDate"];
                    newRow["ExpirationDate"] = schip.["ExpirationDate"];
                    newRow["CCMSIAdjusterID"] = schip.["CCMSIAdjusterID"];
                }

                td.Rows.Add(newRow);

                td.AcceptChanges();
            }


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "ErrorMessage", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };

}
```

Comment: If you plan to use values from your Object variable, you are better off creating DataSet object and assigning these values to it. Reason - SSIS For Loop can process DataSet and get rows from it, but it will not work with your multidim lists; you would end in creating more script tasks and transforms.

Comment: Ferdipux is correct the list/multi dimensional array is not likely to get you where you want to go.  However, what is the data type for your variable "importFile"?  Also have defined it in the appropriate scope in your package and made it available as writable to your script?  An approach I use for the exact same issue is to regex replace the all of the line endings and standardize them then save the file and let the rest of package import just like a standard flat file etc.

Comment: Thank you Ferdipux and Matt. "importFile" is my Object variable, is at the package level, and is a read/write variable in this Script Task. I've not been able to work out any regex logic that is successful - I think the blank cells and/or missing text delimiters are causing most of the problems.